# Having different two different public IPs or Xen guests

Tags: centos, virtualization, xen

I'm using XenServer and CentOS. I have successfully configured two Windows Server guests and they both work properly.

On the host machine, I have `xenbr0`, `xenbr0:0` and `xenbr0:1` (for two different IP ranges)

The problem with the guests is that they public IPs are the same and it's the `xenbr0` IP. For instance, when I go to http://www.whatsmyip.org/ on the guests, they both show the `xenbr0`'s IP (which is host's IP, too)

What I want is to have guest's IP as their public IP as well. Is this even possible?

Comment: Management network on br0 ? I would add a nic to the xen for vm traffic, and give the public IP by there. (as the management network should be in a private lan)

Comment: What does the IP config on the guests say? I suspect they are NAT'ed, so it would be 10.x.x.x, 192.168.x.x, etc.